# Cumulatively count how many times a condition has ocurred in a row

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, cumsum

In a `data.table` (or a `data.frame`), how can I count "cumulatively" how many times such condition has occurred in a row?

To illustrate,

```
DT <- data.table(A=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 B=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1))
```

If I would like to add a column `C` that indicates

- if (A==B), add 1 to the value above current row.
- if (A!=B), start again with 0

So the answer would be

```
DT <- data.table(A=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 B=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                 C=c(1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1)]
```

It seems simple but I can't seem to do it. I'm guessing that it could build on something like this?

```
DT[,C:=ifelse(A==B, ??, 0)]
```

Also, I'm afraid it may be a duplicate question but can't seen to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using `rleid` to create a grouping variable on 'B', then multiply the sequence of rows with 'B' to create the 'C'

```
DT[, C := seq_len(.N)*B, .(A, rleid(B))]
DT
#    A B C
# 1: 1 1 1
# 2: 1 0 0
# 3: 1 1 1
# 4: 1 1 2
# 5: 1 0 0
# 6: 1 1 1
# 7: 1 1 2
# 8: 1 1 3
# 9: 1 0 0
#10: 1 1 1
#11: 1 1 2
#12: 1 1 3
#13: 1 1 4
#14: 1 0 0
#15: 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave` in `base` R:

```
x <- with(dt, A==B)
cbind(dt, C = ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = cumsum))

   # A B C
 # 1: 1 1 1
 # 2: 1 0 0
 # 3: 1 1 1
 # 4: 1 1 2
 # 5: 1 0 0
 # 6: 1 1 1
 # 7: 1 1 2
 # 8: 1 1 3
 # 9: 1 0 0
# 10: 1 1 1
# 11: 1 1 2
# 12: 1 1 3
# 13: 1 1 4
# 14: 1 0 0
# 15: 1 1 1
```